# How do I split a comma-separated string?

Tags: vb.net

I have a comma-separated string. For example,

```
{"one,two,three"}
```

Can I create an array from this and if so, how? In VB.NET.

Comment: See [`String.Split()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.split(v=vs.110).aspx)

Answer (score 27, accepted):

```
    ' you want to split this input string
    Dim s As String = "one,two,three"

    ' Split string based on comma
    Dim words As String() = s.Split(New Char() {","c})

    ' Use For Each loop over words and display them

    Dim word As String
    For Each word In words
        Console.WriteLine(word)
    Next
```

Answer (score 9):

Like this:

```
dim str as string = "one,two,three"
dim str2() as string = split(str, ",")
```

Reference:

- [Split Function (Visual Basic)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6x627e5f(v=vs.90).aspx)

Comment: As it stood your code referenced `String.Split` as mentioned in Abbas's answer, but called it with a `String` which would only work with `Option Strict Off`. I've adjusted it to use `Strngs.Split`, because it's a useful "VBism", and that is what you've referenced in the link.

Answer (score -1):

Each item to string VB.NET like it if it is used for you:

```
Dim itmsF = New StringBuilder()

For Each item As String In list
    itmsF.Append("'" + item + "'").Append(",")
Next

Dim queryItems = itmsF.Remove(itmsF.Length - 1, 1).ToString()
```

#### Output

```
// 'idea', 'mango','foo'
```