# Break down data from textbox Visual Basic 2013

Tags: vb.net, arduino

I am trying to read data from a textbox. The data consists of 2 data.

For example: "180,10."

I wish to get 180 and put it in a variable, and 10 on a separate variable.
I wish to know how I can start reading or end reading at a certain character like "," or ".".
I am reading specifically from a serial port and my code is:

```
receivedData = ReceiveSerialData()
RichTextBox1.Text &= receivedData
```

I tried looking for it but I can't semm to find an answer. Hope you can help me. Thanks.

Comment: `String.Split` is your friend here...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I split a comma separated string?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27035042/how-do-i-split-a-comma-separated-string)

Comment: "I am trying to read data from a textbox". Are you really? "I am reading specifically from a serial port". That's not a `TextBox`. A `String` is a `String` so we can work out what we need to know in this particular case but there will be other cases where, if you can't explain what you're actually doing, we won't be able to work it out for ourselves. You need to provide a FULL and CLEAR explanation of the problem. If you're not reading from a `TextBox` then don't say you are. A `RichTextBox` isn't a `TextBox` either. Everything has a name so use that name, not something similar but different.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you considered using [String.Split()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.split)?  Using that method, you can specify on what character(s) you wish to split your `string`.  The `Split()` method will return a `string` array containing the split parts of your `string`.

Example:

```
Module Module1

    Sub Main()
        Dim exampleString As String = "180,10"
        Dim stringElements As String() = exampleString.Split(","C)

        Console.WriteLine(stringElements(0)) 'Prints 180
        Console.WriteLine(stringElements(1)) 'Prints 10
    End Sub

End Module
```

There are various different overloads of `String.Split()` available should your requirements become more complex: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.split