# VB.NET : Get string after a Comma and insert it to Combobox

Tags: string, vb.net

I know this is already asked question and possible to be close, But i need a accurate answer for this. I already searched in internet, Read other question for others, read Documentations and blogs,

**This is my scenario:**

For eg. i have a `String`

`Processed Title: 2017002652, 2017002655, BN-42, H-14356, N-253050, QOCT-1031`

After i run this code,

```
 Dim word As String = "Processed Title: 2017002652, 2017002655, BN-42, H-14356, N-253050, QOCT-1031"
 Dim wordArr As String() = word.Split(": ")
 Dim result As String = wordArr(1)
 txtTitleNo.Text = result
 txtTitleNo.Text = txtTitleNo.Text.Replace(" ", "")
```

The result is something like this,

```
2017002652,2017002655,BN-42,H-14356,N-253050,QOCT-1031
```

The Word `Processed Title` and `:` is removed and also the spaces is removed.

Now i want to achieve is, **i want to get the string separately after the comma and insert to `ComboBox`, so the value of `Combobox` is something like this**.

For eg. the first one is :

`2017002652`

second is :

`2017002655`

third is :

`BN-42`

and so on ..

Any ideas will be a big help.

Comment: `Dim ArrayOfString As String() = txtTitleNo.Text.Split(',')` resulting an array of splitted strings by comma. Then you can assign it to each comboboxes.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I split a comma separated string?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27035042/how-do-i-split-a-comma-separated-string)

Comment: `combobox.DataSource = word.Split(": ")(1).Split(", ").ToList()`

Answer (score 0):

You could always just run `string.split()` again:

```
Dim word As String = "Processed Title: 2017002652, 2017002655, BN-42, H-14356, N-253050, QOCT-1031"
Dim wordArr As String() = word.Split(": ")(1).Split(", ")
For Each result As String In wordArr
    Console.WriteLine(result)
Next
```

alternatively, if you want a "pretty" one step solution you can use a Regex

Regex:
`(?<=: |, )[^,]+`

```
Imports System
Imports System.Text.RegularExpressions

Public Module Module1

    Public Sub Main()
        For Each result As Match In Regex.Matches("Processed Title: 2017002652, 2017002655, BN-42, H-14356, N-253050, QOCT-1031", "(?<=: |, )[^,]+")
            Console.WriteLine(result.Value)
        Next
    End Sub
End Module
```

[Demonstration](https://dotnetfiddle.net/CZUGea)